# Call JavaScript function when div is loaded in Partial Page in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Partial page in which I am loading div elements. I want to call a JavaScript function when each div is loaded in my partial view.

```
<p class="m-0" onload="markMessageAsDelivered('@item.isDelivered')">@item.Message</p>
```

This is the function I have in my JS in my razor page.

```
function markChatAsDelivered(isDelivered) {
            if (!isDelivered)
                alert('markChatAsDelivered');
        }
```

This function is not getting called. I tried to put it in windows onload as well but still it is not working. Please let me know what can be done?

Comment: The `load` event only works on the document and img elements. For this to work it would make more sense to just call the function when you append that HTML to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

The problem I've had with these things is that `onload` is called before ASP.NET makes its changes to the page. There's two solutions I use:

1. `$(document).ready()` with JQuery waits until the DOM is fully loaded and done, so you can migrate some code into there.
2. `function pageLoad(sender, args)` is a built-in ASP JS function (like Page_Load in your code behind) that gets called when the page is done being loaded. You can migrate some JS into here like the first answer.

Personally, even though I like to avoid libraries, I like the first option because you can use more than one per page. This is only really useful if you're calling code in your master page though. The second option is good if you only use it once per page, but obviously if you try to use it in both your master page and current page, it won't work properly. So I'd recommend JQuery, but if you must avoid it, pageLoad works too.